# How to setup sonarlint as a git precommit hook?

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis, lint, sonarlint

I was exploring on linting tools for java and decided to use sonarlint plugin on IntelliJ Idea. Now, I'm finding it difficult on how to integrate sonarlint with a git precommit hook. This is to enforce my teammates to resolve all the issues and bugs reported by Sonarlint before committing the code.

Also, I'm not looking for hosting a SonarQube server just for this. Is there someway to add a configuration within codebase and enable the linting on git precommit?

Comment: SonarLint triggers a pre-commit analysis if you commit via the IDE UI. They also implemented a new setting to focus on new code, meaning only the issues that will affect the quality gate status are reported. Regarding the pre-commit hook, given this [topic](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/pre-commit-hooks/87674) on their community, it's not officially available as of today.